# Member function redeclaration not allowed

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

If I define the function in mainwindow.cpp the function works, but when I define it in radiobuttons.cpp, and attempt to call it from mainwindow.cpp, the project won't compile.

**mainwindow.h**

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H        
    #include <QMainWindow>

    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

        public:
            explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

            void build_radios();  //this function

            ~MainWindow();

    };    
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**radiobuttons.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    void MainWindow::build_radios()
     {  

    //... some code

     }
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

void MainWindow::radio_buttons();   //error: C2761: 'void MainWindow::build_radios(void)' : member function redeclaration not allowed

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{

radio_buttons();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a definition, the compiler sees it as a declaration of a member function outside the class definition, which is illegal. Just remove that line. It shouldn't be there in the first place, it has no use.

In fact, move the actual definition from `radiobuttons.cpp` to `mainwindow.cpp` for consistency. Why declare a `MainWindow` member in a different implementation file?

Comment: if I remove that line from mainwindow.cpp, i get :mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall MainWindow::build_radios(void)" (?build_radios@MainWindow@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)

Comment: and I'm just trying to organize my code better, mainwindow.cpp has gotten very long

Comment: @user1846123 that's a different issue and it's telling you you're not compiling the file `mainwindow.cpp`.

Comment: @user1846123 that's not better. If it's getting too long (haha) consider a `mainwindow2.cpp`.

Comment: how is making mainwindow2.cpp better than radiobuttons.cpp?

Comment: @user1846123 because `mainwindow2.cpp` has something to do with the `MainWindow` class. `radiobutton.cpp` doesn't. (Don't you see the relation? One class, one file. That's how it's readable and well-organized.)

Comment: I see. For organization's sake. Yes makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

> but when I define it in radiobuttons.cpp...

Except that you don't **define** but re-**declare** it. (And even that's redundant since you have the header file of the class included in that particular file.) The error message says pretty much what the problem is:

> member function redeclaration not allowed

When you declare the `MainWindow` class, you have the `void build_radios();` declaration inside - that in itself is enough for declaring the method. In the .cpp file, it's sufficient to implement it only, i. e. provide a definition **only** - you already have a declaration, coming from declaration of the class in the header file.

(In fact, you also have a definition, but that's in the `radiobuttons.cpp` file - it should be in the `mainwindow.cpp`. Fit all the methods of a class into one implementation file, don't speread them across multiple files and classes and... and... and...)